# How can iterative algorithm over a dynamically changed collection with depended condition be written functionally?

Tags: recursion, graph, f#, functional-programming, immutability

I have the algorithm that deletes unreachable nodes of graph starting with specified node and according to input list of edge marks:

[image]

```
let g = Set.ofList [ (0, false, 1);
                     (0, true, 2);
                     (1, true, 3);
                     (1, false, 4);
                     (2, true, 4);
                     (4, false, 4); ]

let nextNode graph prev value = graph |> Seq.tryPick (function
    | prev', value', next when prev = prev' && value = value' -> Some next
    | _ -> None)

let noIncoming graph node =
            not <| Set.exists (fun (_, _, node') -> node = node') graph

let clearEdges graph start input =
    let graph' = ref graph
    let current = ref (Some start)
    input
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun _ -> Option.exists (noIncoming !graph') !current)
    |> Seq.iter (fun value ->
            let next = nextNode !graph' (!current).Value value
            graph' := Set.filter (fun (current', _, _) -> (!current).Value <> current') !graph'
            current := next)
    graph'

clearEdges g 0 [false; true]
```

> ```
> > val it : Set<int * bool * int> ref =
>   {contents = set [(2, true, 4); (4, false, 4)];}
> ```

It works, but I suspect that my algorithm `clearEdges` with references is ugly and is not F#-styled, as far as I understand. I have tried to write it functionally, but probably I've received the mix of iterative algorithm and collection methods. Is there any functional approach to do that? Because I consider that ugly working code is worse than no code. Thanks.

Comment: You can probably get rid of the mutators by making them arguments of a (private) recursive implementation function. Once you've done that, you may realise that you can reduce it all to a left or right fold. See [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/12/01/recurse) for more details on the process. If you can't reduce the problem to a fold, then [make sure that your implementation is tail-recursive](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/12/22/tail-recurse).

Comment: I'd be happy to help with this particular problem, but I don't understand what `clearEdges` does. Can you elaborate on what `input` is, and why you do a `Seq.takeWhile` over it while ignoring its values?

Comment: If you want to make it functional you shouldn't have any mutations/side effects meaning that you should create a new graph object. Also it's recommended to use structures to describe graph:     type Node = { id: int; left : Node; right : Node }

Comment: It looks like `input` is the path to take through the graph from the starting point. We are trying to return the edges that touch nodes that were not touched by the path.

Comment: @GuyCoder I would think it's not a tree, because it has a cycle in it.

Comment: In answer by Vandroiy `Please document exactly in your resulting code what this function is doing and why!` Remember the easier you make it for those helping you the better the answers will be.

Comment: I'm sorry for unclarity of the code. It have been clear to me when I had just wrote it, but now I can see that code is far not obvious. I'm very grateful to Guy Coder who described in detail what is happening there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have said in the answers and comments, the hardest part about answering this is understanding the code. It lacks a good description and comments.

The first thing I did to understand the code was to add the type signatures and then `printfn` statements to your code to see what it was doing.

After that it because much easier to understand the code in the question.

In redesigning the code I did not try to change small parts at a time but started from scratch building up the core functions based on what I learned from the `printfn` output and type signatures. Without hesitation I switched from the mutable code using `ref` to an immutable graph that was rebuilt from scratch in each function. That may seem like a waste to throw out an existing data structure and construct a new one each time, but think about it this way: the functions that have to make a decision on each edge have to visit each edge so when you visit each edge you either add it to the new graph or don't, that makes coding it much easier and also much easier for others trying to understand it.

I also added the types to make the type signatures more meaningful and to add clarity to what the code is doing. Big bonus for a little bit of work.

I then looked at the functions and instead of focusing on making the code as concise as possible focused on readability and maintainability, and factored a function to make it more pronounced.

Clearly this answer is longer than the other two, but is more functional than the original code, no mutables, easier to understand on the first read, and commented to explain what each function does.

If this were to be part of a library the code should be modified to remove the type signatures and if this were to be generic that would not be an option. Also make the separate functions inner functions and refactor some of it down to make use of built-in F# core functions and add more comments to compensate for the loss of clarity when doing so.

In an earlier version I used [List.pick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370236(v=vs.120).aspx) but realized it could throw a `KeyNotFoundException` exception and since I like my functions to be [total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Total_function) when possible modified it to avoid the exception.

In looking at my answer I was not happy with `if not (nodeUsed graph node) then`; it was a wart in the middle of simplicity. So I decided to resort to the old Swiss army knife of functional programming: [factoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization). [Pure functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) programming is basically expressions that can be factored like math expressions, or more theoretically [term rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting#Term_rewriting_systems). I knew if I could factor out the line with the `not` I could make it more beautiful and this easier to comprehend. So the way to factor out the `not` was to move it outside of the `let rec`, e.g. `pathToNodes`, and that could be done by passing in a list of nodes instead of a list of transitions, e.g. `reduceGraph2`. Once that was done the code reached simplicity.

I am sure one can factor the code down more but I typically leave my answers like this for the new F# people because they are easier to comprehend.

```
namespace Workspace

module main =

    type Node = int
    type Transition = bool
    type Edge = Node * Transition * Node
    type Path = Transition list
    type Graph = Edge list

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 

        let edge1 : Edge =  (0, false, 1)
        let edge2 : Edge =  (0, true , 2)
        let edge3 : Edge =  (1, true , 3)
        let edge4 : Edge =  (1, false, 4)
        let edge5 : Edge =  (2, true , 4)
        let edge6 : Edge =  (4, false, 4)

        let g : Graph = [edge1; edge2; edge3; edge4; edge5; edge6]

        // Given a Node, are there any Edges to that node
        let nodeUsed (graph : Graph) (checkNode : Node) : bool =
            List.exists (fun (_, _, toNode) -> checkNode = toNode) graph

        // Given a Node and a transition, what is the next node
        // This assumes that Transition is binary 
        // so only a value will be returned instead of a list.
        let nextNode (graph : Graph) (fromNode : Node) (transition : Transition) : Node option = 
            let rec pick (graph : Graph) (fromNode : Node) (transition : Transition) : Node option =
                match graph with
                | (f, c, t)::tl when (f = fromNode) && (c = transition) -> Some t
                | hd::tl -> pick tl fromNode transition
                | _ -> None
            pick graph fromNode transition

        // Given a graph and a node, remove all edges that start from that node.
        // This builds a new graph each time, thus the graph is immutable.
        let removeNode (graph : Graph) (node : Node) : Graph =
            let rec removeEdges graph node newGraph =
                match graph with
                | hd::tl ->
                    let (f,c,t) = hd
                    if (f = node) 
                    // Don't add current node to new graph
                    then removeEdges tl node newGraph 
                    // Add current node to new graph
                    else removeEdges tl node ((f,c,t) :: newGraph)  
                | [] -> newGraph
            removeEdges graph node []

        // or

        // let removeNode (graph : Graph) (node : Node) : Graph =
        //     let choiceFunction elem =
        //         match elem with
        //         | (f,c,t) when f = node -> None
        //         | _ -> Some(elem)
        //     List.choose choiceFunction graph

        // Given a graph, a starting node, and a list of transitions (path), 
        // return a new reduced graph based on the example code in the SO question.
        let reduceGraph (graph : Graph) (start : Node) (path : Path)  : Graph =
            let rec processTransistion graph node transitions =
                if not (nodeUsed graph node) then 
                    match transitions with
                    | (transistion :: transitions) ->
                        // Get next node before removing nodes used to get next node
                        let nextNodeResult = nextNode graph node transistion
                        match nextNodeResult with
                        | Some(nextNode) ->
                            let newGraph = removeNode graph node
                            processTransistion newGraph nextNode transitions
                        | None -> graph
                    | [] -> graph
                else graph
            processTransistion graph start path

        let result = reduceGraph g 0 [false; true]
        printfn "reduceGraph - result: %A" result

        printf "Press any key to exit: "
        System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
        printfn ""

        0 // return an integer exit code
```

.

```
    // Give an graph, a node and a path, 
    // convert the transition list (path) to a node list
    let pathToNodes (graph : Graph) (start : Node) (path : Path) : (Node List) =
        let rec visit graph node transistions acc =
            match transistions with
            | (transition::rest) -> 
                match (nextNode graph node transition) with
                | Some(nextNode) -> visit graph nextNode rest (nextNode :: acc)
                | None -> List.rev acc
            | [] -> List.rev acc
        visit graph start path [start]

    // Given a graph, a starting node, and a list of transitions (path), 
    // return a new reduced graph based on the example code in the SO question.
    // This variation does so internally by a node list instead of a transition list
    let reduceGraph2 (graph : Graph) (start : Node) (path : Path) : Graph =
        let rec processNodes graph nodes =
            match nodes with
            | (currentNode :: rest) -> processNodes (removeNode graph currentNode) rest
            | [] -> graph
        let nodes = pathToNodes graph start path
        processNodes graph nodes
```

Answer (score 5):

Please document in your resulting code what this function is doing and why! It took me a while to figure out what is going on, as I didn't expect `clearEdges` to go over a fixed list of hops with two abort conditions while deleting outgoing edges.

You could change the data structure to this, which adds some type safety and makes traversing the graph easier:

```
type Node = Node of int

let g = Map.ofList [ (Node 0, false), Node 1
                     (Node 0, true),  Node 2
                     (Node 1, true),  Node 3
                     (Node 1, false), Node 4
                     (Node 2, true),  Node 4
                     (Node 4, false), Node 4 ]
```

Then, `clearEdges` can be written like this:

```
let rec clearEdges graph node hopList =
    if List.isEmpty hopList || Map.exists (fun _ dst -> dst = node) graph then graph
    else let graph' = Map.filter (fun (src, _) _ -> src <> node ) graph
         match Map.tryFind (node, hopList.Head) graph with
         | None -> graph'
         | Some node -> clearEdges graph' node hopList.Tail
```

with no further functions required. The call changes to `clearEdges g (Node 0) [false; true]`.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by others, you probably want to remove the re-assignment through the use of a ref cell and instead accumulate some state using a fold or recursion. Here's what I came up with:

```
let reachedNodes graph start fullPath =
    let rec loop path acc node =
        match path with
        | [] -> node :: acc
        | v :: rest ->
            let next =
                graph
                |> Seq.tryPick (fun (prev, value, next) ->
                    if prev = node && value = v then Some next
                    else None)
            match next with
            | Some c -> loop rest (node :: acc) c
            | None -> node :: acc
    loop fullPath [] start
    |> Set.ofList

let clearEdges graph start path =
    let reachedNodes' = reachedNodes graph start path
    let notInReachedNodes n = Set.contains n reachedNodes' |> not
    graph
    |> Set.filter (fun (prev, _, next) -> notInReachedNodes prev && notInReachedNodes next)
```

You used a set of edges to represent your graph. This prevents a completely duplicated edge, but it still allows apparently illegal states: e.g. `0` could have two outgoing `true` edges to different nodes. It might be better to represent your graph as a map of `(node, value)` to `node`. This could also improve the performance for this case because you would be taking advantage of the map's key lookup.

Comment: I thought about using Map, but I haven't knew what it is really right approach, thanks. Probably the decision with preliminary path finding isn't work because the input `[true; true]` gives result `[(1, true, 3)]` instead of `[(1, false, 4); (1, true, 3); (4, false, 4)]`